# Query editor is gone, how can I make it reappear?

Tags: kql, kusto-explorer

Whenever I open Kusto explorer, the query editor is immediately displayed and I can see my code. For some reason today, that's not happening so I can't look at old code or write new ones. How can I make the query editor reappear?

[image]

Note: after a long time trying to figure this out with no results, I closed and opened Kusto explorer for the second time, and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

version `1.0.3.1314` or later was published to address this issue, please update to that if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to close and open again Kusto explorer and it did not work, but then I tried to do that a second time and it seemed to do the trick. Not sure why the query editor wasn't showing this morning.